# Resque Scheduler plugin for the scheduled job not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I am using this plugin for scheduled job.But it is not working.
I am confused about some points,Should I need to create the Job class and set their name in to schedule file?When testing it then,Should I run the rescue scheduler and Resque worker both or only one of them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you launch the resque-scheduler task, with the resque:works task ?

Comment: Yes,I launced it. Should I need to start worker of Resque also? And I am using this schedule file for every minute Job it is also not running. Here is my schedule create_ams_daily_mailer:
  cron: "*/1 * * * *"
  queue: daily_mailer_job
  class: AmsDailyMailer
  args:
  rails_env: demo, staging, production,development
  description: "This job will send the mail to subscribed user"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My Resque Scheduler config... you will mostly need all these pieces:

**YML file (config/resque_scheduler.yml):**

```
every_1_minute:
  cron: "* * * * *"
  class: EveryMinute
  queue: some_queue
  description: Tasks to perform every minute
```

**config/initializers/resque.rb:**

```
require 'resque_scheduler'
Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'config/resque_scheduler.yml'))
```

**Ruby class (lib/every_minute.rb or somewhere in the load path):**

```
class EveryMinute
  def self.perform
    puts "Hello every minute!"
  end
end
```

You need to run

```
rake resque:scheduler
rake resque:work
```

The resque:scheduler process periodically queues up jobs, hence the scheduling. And the workers will just do the jobs blindly. This is why you need BOTH to successfully schedule and run jobs periodically.